# ¿Cuánto tiempo duran las aplicaciones de prueba de Xcode en un iPhone antes de caducar?

Tags: xcode, iphone

Al instalar una aplicación de un iPhone desde Xcode, estas tienen un tiempo de caducidad. Pasado ese tiempo (el cual desconozco) la aplicación deja de funcionar.

Solo necesito saber cuánto tiempo tiene una aplicación antes de caducar.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: [Según esta respuesta](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/51527) el certificado dura una semana. En [otras respuestas en Stackoverflow en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38307356/5587982) dicen que depende de otros factores. Desde XCode puedes ver la fecha en que expira la App de prueba. El tiempo límite, según algunos, es más largo si tienes una cuenta desarrollador (de pago)... Y puedes también comprar un certificado que permitiría tener mayor límite de tiempo de prueba. Lo que no he encontrado a sido documentación oficial donde se explique este tema.

Answer (score 0):

Se puede observar en la sección Provisioning Profile de tu tarjet. Al presionar sobre el símbolo de ayuda ( i ).

Tienes 6 días de prueba antes de tener que renovarse automáticamente, los cuales empiezan a contar desde que empiezas el proyecto, y no desde que instalas la aplicación en el celular.